# Center location for a list of latitude/longitudes

Tags: c#, geospatial, asp.net-core-3.1

I currently have an array of locations (with lat/lon) and would like to know how to find a rough center location for all the Locations within the list for C# please.

The examples I have found are in different programming languages. I would post what I have worked out so far but I'm just stuck on where to even begin.

Thanks

```
public (double lat, double lon) GetCenterLocation(Location[] locs)
{

}


public class Location {

    public long Id {get;set;}

    public double Latitude {get;set;}

    public double Longitude {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: Get min/max latitude and longitude.  The rough center is  (max - min)/2 + min.

Comment: You would need to define what center means first.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. If there's a group of locations, if should be an average. Not sure how to describe it. If 3 locations and close to each other but one is miles and miles away. It should be closer to the 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used averages of both lat and lon values from a list to get the center. The 53.409533, 0.974654 is so that I at least get something back.

```
public static (double Latitude, double Longitude) GetCenter(this List<LatLngPoint> points)
{
    if (points == null || points.Count == 0)
        return (53.409533, 0.974654);

    var lat = points.Where(ll => ll.Latitude.HasValue).Average(ll => ll.Latitude.Value);
    var lon = points.Where(ll => ll.Longitude.HasValue).Average(ll => ll.Longitude.Value);

    return (lat, lon);
}
```